# PyQt - Set QLabel image from URL

Tags: python, pyqt

I've been trying to set an image to a QLabel from a URL. But im having no luck. 
Here is how im trying to do it right now:

```
import urllib, cStringIO
img_file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(image_url).read())
image_file = Image.open(img_file)
```

Then setting this to a QImage:

```
final_image = QImage(image_file)

self.emit(SIGNAL("finished(QImage)"),
    final_image
)
```

The image is getting passed back from a thread to a method in the main GUI.

```
def set_image(self, final_image):
    self.main_picture_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(final_image).scaled(
        QSize(self.picture_label.size()), 
        Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
        Qt.FastTransformation
    )
    self.picture_label.setPixmap(self.main_picture_pixmap)
```

Doing this I get the error:

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

Is there anyway to fix this, or a different way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QImage.load`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#load) takes a filename, not the image data. If you want to do that, you need to use `QImage.loadFromData`.

Comment: I tried that and i get the error
""" QImage.loadFromData(str, str format=None): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QImage' """
Maybe i'm not reading the url right to store it into a string?

Comment: The clue is `unbound method`: you have to use it on an instance of `QImage` not on the class. [This](http://pastebin.com/2h6JHkBh) should work

Comment: Awesome! It works, thank you! The problem was the image fetching from the URL.

Answer (score 8):

Simple formula to load an image from a url into an icon.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
import urllib

url = 'http://example.com/image.png'    
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(data)
icon = QIcon(pixmap)
```