# access image from URL in pushbutton in pyqt4 [Python]

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to add image to pushbutton directly from using the URL in pyqt4. To which i'm unsuccessful.adding the image from the image stored in system is possible.Hence any suggestions or advice would be grateful.

Thank you

```
`import sys
 from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
 from PyQt4.QtGui import *
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *  

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Entry_view(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(25, 25, 800, 480)

        timer = QTimer()

        t1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Tool1",self)

        font = QtGui.QFont()

        t1.setFont(font)
        t1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("t1"))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()                # Image has been added to the tool
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('http://www.siliconsemiconductor.net/images/news/195481055397707.jpg')), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        t1.setIcon(icon1)
        t1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(170, 170))
        t1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("t1"))
        # t1.clicked.connect(self.Tool_Image_Ext)
        t1.resize(400,255)
        t1.move(0, 0)
        self.Tool_Image_Ext()
        self.show()`
```

Comment: first download file on local disk.

Comment: Issue is that i want to access directly from the url and at that particular url the image has been has changed then how to update it.

Comment: `QPixmap` can't read/download from server so you have to read/download on your own. You can read from server (using `urllib`, `requests`, etc.) and: (a) save on local disk, and open from this file, (b) create file-like object in memory which you can use like local file - see: `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO`

Comment: BTW: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20273362/1832058

Comment: hi i tried to use the process use said but was unable to display image,below is the code i tried

Comment: '     url3 = 'http://www.perfectlyintune.com/page34/page35/files/apple-logo-0028640x4800029.jpg'  
        data = urllib.urlopen(url3).read()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(data), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off) '

Comment: @furas thanks i was able to solve the issue .the attached code below is the solution.


'data = urllib.urlretrieve("https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg","image1.jpg")
               icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:\PythonFolder\Codes\image1.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)'

Comment: you can put your solution as a answer (and later mark as accepted). Or you can append at the end of your question - to make it more readable and usefull for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is added in following code.The image in url should be downloaded in a separate file name.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
import urllib
import cStringIO
from urllib import urlopen
import requests

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Entry_view(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(25, 25, 800, 480)

        t1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Tool1",self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        t1.setFont(font)
        t1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("t1"))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()  # Image has been added to the tool
        data = urllib.urlretrieve("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/be/Google_Chrome_for_Android-_Android_5.0_Logo.png","image1.png")
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("D:PythonFolder\Codes\image1.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        t1.setIcon(icon1)
        t1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(170, 170))
        t1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("t1"))
        t1.resize(400,255)
        t1.move(0, 0)
        self.show()            

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

     myapp = Entry_view()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```